# std::is_function does not recognize template argument as function

Tags: c++, types, c++11

I am passing a pointer to function into a function template:

```
int f(int a) { return a+1; }

template<typename F>
void use(F f) {
    static_assert(std::is_function<F>::value, "Function required"); 
}

int main() {
    use(&f); // Plain f does not work either.
}
```

But the template argument `F` is not recognized by `is_function` to be a function and the static assertion fails. Compiler error message says that `F` is `int(*)(int)` which is a pointer to function. Why does it behave like that? How can I recognize the function or pointer to function in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`F` is a *pointer to function* (regardless of whether you pass `f` or `&f`). So remove the pointer:

```
std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<F>::type>::value
```

(Ironically, `std::is_function<std::function<FT>> == false` ;-))

Comment: I loathe implicit conversions :(

Comment: *"(Ironically, `std::is_function<std::function<FT>> == false` ;-))"* - Maybe for future standards a `std::is_callable` might be a good idea, since `std::is_function` doesn't even work for lambdas, just simple functions (and the times each callable was a function are way over in modern C++).

Comment: @ChristianRau `std::is_function` is one of the primary classification traits. `is_callable` or anything like that would serve a completely different purpose altogether.

Comment: @LucDanton Yes, of course. Nobody argues that `std::is_function` has its value and fits perfectly to things like `std::is_array` (which should *not* return true for `std::array` either) or `std::is_class`. But nevertheless an *additional* `std::is_callable` would be a nice idea and would be in line with other rather high-level traits, like (the AFAIK already proposed) `std::is_swappable` and the desperately needed (though AFAIK not proposed) `std::is_hashable`.